# Why can I not check instance type after class cast exception?

Tags: android, android-studio, code-inspection

Can anybody explain to me why the following block of code is highlighted as a mistake in Android Studio?

The IDE is saying `elem instanceof SubtypeB` is always false - **is this just a mistake by the inspector or is this a real language detail I need to learn about?**. Can I safely suppress the warning and keep the current code?

Example code:

```
for (Parcelable elem : list) {
    try {
        listOfSubtypeA.add( (SubtypeA) elem );
    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
        //Line below is highlighted as always false
        if (elem instanceof SubtypeB) {
            ... //just logging
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What relationship is there between `SubtypeB` and `Parcelable` ?

Comment: SubtypeA/B implement Parcelable here

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Do you get the error with your paraphrased version? Can you provide a minimal example with all relevant code?

Comment: What is the relation between `SubtypeA`and `SubtypeB`?

Comment: @k5 it's trivial to reproduce, I've already given the minimal example but I added a picture just for you

Comment: Please supply a complete program, as text not a picture.

Comment: If list actually contained a `SubtypeB` the if is reached an true. So the check is thrown off by something. As your picture seems to contain compile errors without compile error markings. It isn't that trustworthy.

Comment: There's no compile errors, it's just marking the items as unused since it's just  a demo block

Comment: @Willem that's even more confusing then, but may be the answer to my question - the IDE is probably making a mistake (I've already tried invalidating caches)

Comment: @Temporary I did not downvote. I prefer making suggestions for improving the question in comments. If you post a demo program as text, I can copy-paste it into an IDE window and compile exactly what you are compiling, with no risk of typos. If you post a partial program and I try to expand it to a compilable program there is a risk I'll make choices that prevent the problem. If you post a complete demo program, that risk is also eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is incorrect from your IDE. Just run it:

```
 interface Test123  { }
static class SubtypeA implements Test123{ }
static class SubtypeB implements Test123 { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Test123> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SubtypeB());
    List<SubtypeA> subList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Test123 elem : list) {
        try {
            subList.add( (SubtypeA) elem );
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            //Line below is highlighted as always false
            if (elem instanceof SubtypeB) {
                System.out.println("cce = " + cce);
        //just logging
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will see that the statement `if (elem instanceof SubtypeB)` turns out to be true so your IDE doesn't detect it correct

Comment: This is what I'd expect, my own code also compiles, I just don't want to risk that it crashes in production. I tested your code out of curiosity and it is also highlighted in my IDE. I think I'm just going to suppress it, thanks

Comment: I get that, maybe you can discuss it with your colleagues